# Unable to compile .c program linking openssl

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, openssl

I have the following simple openssl program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>

int main() {
    AES_KEY aes;
    unsigned char key[] = {0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A,
                           0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A, 0x5A};

    int result;
    result = AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &aes);
    if (result < 0) {
        printf(Unable to generate key: "%i", result);
        exit(-1);
    }

    // Each round is 16 bytes (128 bits)
    for (int i = 0; i < (aes.rounds + 1) * 4; i = i + 4) {
        printf("0x%x 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x\n", aes.rd_key[i], aes.rd_key[i+1], aes.rd_key[i+2], aes.rd_key[i+3]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and I'm trying to compile it with the command

```
gcc -I/usr/local/include/openssl -o generateKey -lcrypto -lssl -L/usr/local/lib generatekey.c
```

`/usr/local/include/openssl` contains `aes.h` so that's why I think I need that. `usr/local/lib` contains `libcrypto.a`, `libcrypto.so`, `libssl.a`, and `libssl.so` so that's why I think I need those too. When I try to compile I get the error

```
generate_key.c: undefined reference to `AES_set_encrypt_key`
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is there somewhere else I should be linking to for finding the openssl libraries? I'm running this on Ubuntu 16.04.

I've tried `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev` to ensure openssl is installed for development.

Comment: `-lcrypto -lssl file.c` -> `file.c -lcrypto -lssl`